# Animate Max Height, other elements lag

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

I'm trying to expand the max height of a `ul`. When the max-height property is changed (by toggling a class, the height changes immediately, but the elements underneath the `ul` respect the animated height as they should.

```js
var expander = $('.skill-expand');
var skillsUl = $('.skills-list');
expander.on('click', function() {
  skillsUl.toggleClass('unexpanded');
  if (skillsUl.hasClass('unexpanded')) {
    expander.html('<span class="fa fa-chevron-down">..\/..</span>');
  } else {
    expander.html('<span class="fa fa-chevron-up">../\..</span>');
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
.skills-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  max-height: 800px;
  /*effectively auto*/
}

.skill-expand {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.skills-list.unexpanded {
  max-height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="skills-list unexpanded">
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
</ul>

<a href="#" class="skill-expand"><span class="fa fa-chevron-up">..\/..</span></a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ubgmshzo/

When the `..\/..` expander text is clicked notice the lag between the expander element moving down. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery UI `toggleClass` you can specify a `duration` and using a  `promise` trigger the switch of the up/down chevron.

```js
var expander = $('.skill-expand');
var skillsUl = $('.skills-list');

expander.on('click', function() {
  skillsUl.toggleClass('unexpanded', 1000).promise().done(function() {
    if (skillsUl.hasClass('unexpanded')) {
      expander.find('span').removeClass('fa-chevron-down');
      expander.find('span').addClass('fa-chevron-up');
    } else {
      expander.find('span').removeClass('fa-chevron-up');
      expander.find('span').addClass('fa-chevron-down');
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

```css
.skills-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 800px;
  /*effectively auto*/
}

.skill-expand {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.skills-list.unexpanded {
  max-height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fa-chevron-up:before {
  content: "..\\/..";
}

.fa-chevron-down:before {
  content: "../\\..";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul class="skills-list unexpanded">
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
  <li class="skill-rating">Developers developers</li>
</ul>

<a href="#" class="skill-expand"><span class="fa fa-chevron-up"></span></a>
```

I also moved the `span` `fa-chevron-up` and `fa-chevron-down` into CSS for easier toggling instead of overwriting HTML.